# Website does not load content on mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, angular, firebase

I built a web site by using Angular 2, NodeJS and Firebase and it works perfectly on `localhost`, however after I hosted it on Heroku ([**link**](https://angular2-and-nodejs.herokuapp.com/#/content/all)) it isn't working on mobiles website. Does any one know what is the problem?

If you need some code I have it as well, can attach that part which you will need.

Comment: Your page content is not loading on mobile or your domain is not working for mobile? Do you have any error message displayed in your mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every one , i forgot middleware

```
app.use(function (req , res ,next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods' , '*');
  next();

});
```

so it was reason why i could not access the page